# Parse a date in java using SimpleDateFormat with additional characters

Tags: java, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I have the following date:

```
String data = "20160421095058613000";
```

I want to check whether this is a valid date or not using SimpleDateFormat.
The pattern I want is: `"yyyymmddhhmmssSSS"` 
The problem is that I don't know how to include in this pattern those 3 zeros at the end of the date. 
I've tried:

```
try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmssSSS000").parse(data);
            System.out.println(date);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I get:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20160421095058613000"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:377)
    at testare.main(testare.java:11)
```

Comment: There was a question a few days ago (can't find it anymore) which showed, that `SimpleDateFormat` can't handle the literal `'000'` in a pattern. So you need to remove that.

Comment: Note that your format string is wrong: use `MM` instead of `mm` for months (because `mm` means minutes) and use `HH` instead of `hh` if you need to parse 24-hour instead of 12-hour hours values.

Comment: @Tom can you give me a link to that question?

Comment: @AlexChihaia *"(can't find it anymore)"*  ;P.

Answer (score 3):

You could substring your string into `20160421095058613` and `000`. Then you check if the first string is valid (using SimpleDateFormat) and afterwards you just check if the last 3 characters are zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            String data = "20160421095058613000";
            Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmssSSS").parse(data.substring(0, 17));
                System.out.println(date);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Microseconds

Presumably those last digits represent microseconds. The old legacy date-time classes can only handle milliseconds.

In other words, the last six digits represent the fraction of a second.

Tip: If you have any influence on the source of this data, change to using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when serializing a date-time value to text.

## java.time

You should be using the modern date-time classes in the java.time package.

The java.time classes use a resolution of nanoseconds, for up to nine digits of decimal fraction of a second. More than enough for your six digits of microseconds.

See the `DateTimeFormatter` class for the formatting pattern codes. Quite similar to the old `SimpleDateFormat` codes, but not identical.

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` as you input lacks any info about offset-from-UTC or time zone.

If from the context you know the intended offset or zone, apply it to produce a `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` object.

To interoperate with old code not yet updated to java.time types, you can convert by calling new methods on the old classes. Beware that going from java.time to the old types may mean data loss as any microseconds or nanoseconds are truncated to milliseconds.

All of these issues have been covered many times in other Questions and Answers. Search Stack Overflow for more info and examples.